# How do I print Arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iteration

I have the array:

```
example = ['foo', 'bar', 'quux']
```

I want to iterate over it and print it so it comes out like: `foo bar quux`, not `['foo', 'bar', 'quux']` which would be the case if I used `each` or `for`.

**Note:** I can't just do: `example[0];example[1]`, etc. because the length of the array is variable.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here:

```
puts array.join(' ') # The string contains one space
```

Comment: Can also use `puts array * ' '` - when arrays are multiplied by a string, it performs a join.

Comment: Really? Cool! I did not know that. `join()` is a little clearer though.

Answer (score 5):

```
example.join(" ") #=> foo bar quux.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used `each` to print, it would work fine:

```
example.each {|item| print item; print " " } #=> foo bar quux
```

However, if what you want is a string with the items separated by spaces, that's what the `join` method is for:

```
example.join(' ') #=> "foo bar quux"
```

I suspect your problem is that you're confusing printing with iterating, as `each` just returns the original array — if you want things printed inside of it, you need to actually print like I did in the example above.

Comment: why not just `print item + ' '` or `print "#{item} "`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Because I wanted to make what was going on very explicit and not introduce extra concepts like string interpolation. Anonymous doesn't seem to have a strong grasp on the basics, so I didn't want to throw even more concepts at him/her.

Answer (score 0):

if they may be printed underneath each other just use

```
puts example

=> 
foo
bar
quux
```

otherwise use the solutions from the other answers

```
puts example.join(" ")
```